# Unable to start dnscrypt-proxy on raspbian

Tags: networking, dns, raspbian, dnscrypt

I am using a Raspberry Pi Zero W. The OS is Raspbian Buster. I installed DNSCrypt-Proxy but was unable to start it.

Checked it with `sudo systemctl status dnscrypt-proxy`.

Got `[FATAL] listen udp 127.0.0.1:53: bind: permission denied`.

So checked for who is listening on port 53 with `sudo lsof -i :53`.

Got:

```
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd   1 root   83u  IPv4  12291      0t0  TCP 127.0.2.1:domain (LISTEN)
systemd   1 root   84u  IPv4  12295      0t0  UDP 127.0.2.1:domain
```

Thought, maybe I could fix it by disabling `systemd-resolved`, turns out it was already disabled.

Tried to edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`; added the line `DNSStubListener=no`. Nothing still.

By the way tried also stopping the Avahi daemon.

Any suggestions on what could actually be hogging port 53? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting this problem and not just on Raspbian. I think that the `permission denied` is due to permissions, not the port being in use (the IPs you see are different). When I ran the command manually as root it worked fine.

I downloaded the latest version from Github and installed that per [these instructions.](https://www.itchy.nl/raspberry-pi-4-with-openvpn-pihole-dnscrypt/#dnscrypt) I then did `systemctl edit dnscrypt-proxy` and changed it to the following:

```
[Service]
DynamicUser=yes
AmbientCapabilities=cap_net_bind_service cap_net_broadcast cap_net_admin cap_net_raw
```

The [AmbientCapabilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/488075/63286) seems to be the key that allows it to bind to port 53. Not sure all of those are required but that's what worked for me.

Comment: Cheers, adding the AmbientCapabilities=.. fixed it for me. 
This was after installing dnscrypt-proxy through the Ubuntu 20 repo, on a RPi.